# Sprite reflection?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am new in cocos2d..I have a sprite that is traveling in some direction,  when this sprite hits a wall by an angle, I want it to change the direction and continue in that path..?? can any one give a sample code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this code: [iPhone Cocos2d Bouncing Ball](http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=482).